# jquery filter on multiple array

Tags: jquery, arrays, checkbox, filter

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li data-filters={["red","green","blue"]}>x</li>
    <li data-filters={["red","green","yellow"]}>x</li>
    <li data-filters={["white","green","gray"]}>x</li>
</ul>
```

JQUERY

```
var searchIDs = []; // array used to filter
        $( ".filter_check input:checkbox:checked" ).map(function(){
            searchIDs.push($(this).val());
        });
```

I should hide evry < li > that doesn't have values checked with checkbox. How to do it in jquery?

**UPDATE**

This works, but only selecting one checkbox only. I need to select multiple checkbox

```
$('#container li').each(function(){
            if (!$(this).data('filters').includes(searchIDs)) {
                $(this).hide();
            } else {
                $(this).show(); 
            }
        })
```

**UPDATE**

```
var searchIDs = [];
    function togRow(searchIDs) {
            $('#container_box_result li').each(function(){
                $(this).toggle(
                    searchIDs.every(function (id) {
                        return $(this).data('filters').includes(id)
                    }, this)
                    );
            })
        }

    $(document).on('change', '.filter_check input',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        searchIDs = [];
        $( ".filter_check input:checkbox:checked" ).map(function(){
            searchIDs.push($(this).val());
        });
        console.log(searchIDs);

        togRow($(this).val().split(/\s*,\s*/));
    });
```

Comment: Add a jsfiddle or a snippet for your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `every` and `toggle` like this:

```js
function search(searchIDs) {
    $('#container li').each(function(){
        $(this).toggle(
            searchIDs.every(function (id) {
                return $(this).data('filters').includes(id)
            }, this)
        );
    })
}

$('input').on('input', function() {
    search($(this).val().split(/\s*,\s*/));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Search: <input>
<ul id="container">
    <li data-filters='["red","green","blue"]'>red, green, blue</li>
    <li data-filters='["red","green","yellow"]'>red, green, yellow</li>
    <li data-filters='["white","green","gray"]'>white, green, gray</li>
</ul>
```

This assumes that the values in *searchIDs* must all be included for an entry to be visible. If you want it to behave such that one match is enough, then change `every` to `some` in the code.

Comment: Perfect solution!